# Animate CC - Easeljs - Multiple Draggables and Multiple Target drops

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-animate, easeljs

I'm new to the world of stackoverflow, Javascript, Adobe Animate CC, and EaselJS. All of which I'm in the process of learning how to use. I am trying build a drag and drop activity for html5 canvas that contains 5 draggables and 5 targets. I need the each target to be able to accept and snap [into place] any of the 5 draggable.  The idea is to have the user make 5 choices then check the answers once all 5 draggables have been placed.

There are several examples of EaselJS drag and drop activities around, but the closest one I've found that fits what I need is here on [codepen](http://codepen.io/samualli/pen/xbVGpP?editors=0010). I noticed several other users have used this same example as a starting point too. I've created a branch on codepen from the original posting trying to [show](http://codepen.io/Sweaty_Eddie/pen/BKYmEm?editors=0010) what I am aiming for.

I'm sure there is a better way to code this, but I feel I don't have the knowledge to do so yet. Especially in the branch on codepen where I just copied and pasted to create more draggers and targets. I have made multiple "draggers" and "destinations" each with their own .setBounds then pushed the "destinations" to an array. My plan was to put a for loop around the dragger.on("pressup", function(evt) section and replace all destinations with the array "destinations[i]" containing the pushed content in hopes it would allow me to place any draggable on any target.

This didn't work. I kept getting the same error, via google chrome's developer's tool, stating cannot read property 'getBounds' on undefined. It is referring to this section here, *var objBounds2 = obj2.getBounds().clone();* of the intersect function near the end of the code.

If you're still reading this and are able to following along with what I'm trying to do, then thank you. I'm sure I'm making this more complicated than it really needs to be. I need all the help I can get.

Here is where the display objects are created [draggables and targets.]

```
//VARIABLES
//Drag Object Size
dragRadius = 40;
//Destination Size
destHeight = 100;
destWidth = 100;

//Circle Creation
var label = new createjs.Text("RED", "14px Lato", "#fff");
label.textAlign="center";
label.y -= 7;

var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black")
.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0,0, dragRadius);


//Drag Object Creation
//Placed inside a container to hold both label and shape
var dragger = new createjs.Container();
dragger.x = dragger.y = 100;
dragger.addChild(circle, label);
dragger.setBounds(100, 100, dragRadius*2, dragRadius*2);
//DragRadius * 2 because 2*r = width of the bounding box

var label2 = new createjs.Text("RED", "bold 14px Lato", "#000");
label2.textAlign = "center";
label2.x += 50;
label2.y += 40;


var box = new createjs.Shape();
box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
var destination = new createjs.Container();
destination.x = 350;
destination.y = 50;
destination.setBounds(350, 50, destHeight, destWidth);

destination.addChild(label2, box);
```

Here is the drag and drop section:

```
//DRAG FUNCTIONALITY =====================
dragger.on("pressmove", function(evt){
     evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
     stage.update(); //much smoother because it refreshes the screen every pixel movement instead of the FPS set on the Ticker
     if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
       evt.currentTarget.alpha=0.2;
       box.graphics.clear();
       box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3)
       .beginStroke("#0066A4")
       .rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);

     }else{
       evt.currentTarget.alpha=1;
       box.graphics.clear();     box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
     }

});

//Mouse UP and SNAP====================
dragger.on("pressup", function(evt) {
  if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, destination)){
    dragger.x = destination.x + destWidth/2;
    dragger.y = destination.y + destHeight/2;
    dragger.alpha = 1;
    box.graphics.clear();     
    box.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("black").rect(0, 0, destHeight, destWidth);
    stage.update(evt);
  }
});
```

Here is the function that test the current draggable with the target:

```
//Tests if two objects are intersecting
//Sees if obj1 passes through the first and last line of its
//bounding box in the x and y sectors
//Utilizes globalToLocal to get the x and y of obj1 in relation
//to obj2
//PRE: Must have bounds set for each object
//Post: Returns true or false

  function intersect(obj1, obj2){
  var objBounds1 = obj1.getBounds().clone();
  var objBounds2 = obj2.getBounds().clone();

  var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);

  var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
  var h2 = objBounds2.width / 2;
  var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
  var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;


  if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
  if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;

  return true;
}


//Adds the object into stage
stage.addChild(destination, dragger, destination2, dragger2, destination3, dragger3);
stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
stage.update();
```

*Sorry I don't have rep points to post more links showing other users posts or any images.

Comment: That is quite the sample code block :) I recommend branching that, and trying to make it work in a loop until you run into a specific issue, which is much easier to help with. Note that you will need to somehow associate your targets with their respective boxes, as your current version affects the same box in each dragger.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Lanny.  I'll update the post with any more issues I'm sure I'll run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error too. I'm also really new to EaselJS and Animate CC. What seems to have worked for me (I don't know if this is an actual fix, but it seems to be working for me). I tried using nominalBounds on it but that uses the original, untransformed size of the destination. so I tried this:

```
desination.setBounds(desination.x, desination.y, desination.width, desination.height);
```

I'd just stick that after you have the destination set up, but outside of the pressup, pressmove, or intersect functions.

this  * seems *  to be working for me for now, let me know if it works for you. :)

EDIT: also, I found this by the same guy. He added a few things to it for multiple destinations http://codepen.io/samualli/pen/azNroN/

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I'm excited to try this method out and I will let you know if it works for me.  Also, great find on the Samual Li post.  My mind is kinda blown right now seeing how much coding it took just to get 1 draggable to go to 2 different targets.

Comment: I have been working on 2 different versions of this project.  One is using Li's method which would be a decent amount of coding, and the other using Shapes and a loop to create all display objects (_rather than creating all of them in Animate - turning them into symbols - then placing them in Containers._)  My current issue is that only the very last shape(s) created in the loop is snapping to it's target.

http://codepen.io/Sweaty_Eddie/pen/wGmjbQ

**UPDATE:** my part of the JS in the code above starts @ line 1192 - 1364. The rest of it is generated via Animate CC when published.

Comment: To me, I think the loop for creating it is fine, its where you have the drag.on("pressmove" 'code' ... to me would need to be outside of it. then you'd have an event listener for drag_1, drag_2, ... etc. It's a lot of code, but one thing you could do to shorten it, is have each one of those call a single "drag function" and then a single "drop function" where they all do the same thing while passing the event. Personally I'd do this inside those first pressmove/pressup functions like dragFun(evt); or something like that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh and probably want to do something similar with the targets, because it looks like it's only making the last one a working target. creating it looks fine, it's just the listeners that aren't watching for anything except on the last ones :)

Comment: Good news is I got something working and it seems pretty stable.  I ended up using the first version. Thanks for all the help and advice everyone!

https://jsfiddle.net/Sweaty_Eddie_B/fpgbkubg/

**NOTE**: if you don't see it working on fiddle, try switching the javascript setting to "No wrap - in <body>"